# Exactly one complex connected component in the supercritical phase of the random graph

Tags: probability, combinatorics, graph-theory, random-graphs

> Assume $p=\frac{1+\theta}{n}$ where $\theta\gg n^{-\frac{1}{3}}$. Prove that a.a.s. the random graph $G_{n,p}$ almost surely has exactly one complex component. (A component $C$ is *complex* if it contains at least two distinct cycles. In terms of edges, $C$ is complex iff it contains at last $|C|+1$ edges).

This is problem 2.4.11 from Introduction to Random Graphs by Frieze and Karonski (phrased in terms of $G(n,p)$ rather than $G(n,m)$ for convenience).

My idea is to use staged exposure: write $G_{n,p}=G_{n,p_1}\cup G_{n,p_2}$ where $p_1=\frac{1+\theta/2}{n}$ and $p_2\sim \frac{\theta}{2n}$. Intuitively, it should be that any complex component of $G_{n,p_1}$ is sufficiently large, so adding the edges of $G_{n,p_2}$ will connect them. (Also one should take care of showing that the new edges do not form any new complex components). $p_2\gg \frac{1}{n^{4/3}}$ so it seems like  "sufficiently large" should mean "having $\Omega(n^{2/3})$ vertices" (since $A=O(n^{2/3})$ implies $(1-p_2)^{A^2}\rightarrow 0$).

I tried working out a solution with this idea, but things didn't quite add up. I'd appreciate your help with a hint to further direct me towards the right outline of the proof.

Comment: What do you already know at this point about $G_{n,p_1}$? (That is, what are you fine assuming about $G_{n,p_1}$ without proof, or because you've already proven it?)

Comment: @MishaLavrov Not much, really. My attempt of using the first moment method only led me to the conclusion that it has no complex component of size at most $n^{1/3}$, but this is obviously not enough. Is there anything specific that you are thinking about? I can try to work that out.

Comment: I think that would actually solve the problem if you could also prove that there is already a giant component at this point. (In that case, the other components are much smaller than $n^{1/3}$, so they're not complex!)

Comment: @MishaLavrov I gave it some more thought, and nothing seemed to work. Finally I contacted Alan Frieze. His exact response was "Have a look at Theorem 5.10 of the JLR random graphs book. I don't think that there is a simple solution to the question. If you find
one, let me know." Feel invited to give it a shot if you're interested.